# Why am I getting 2 times data null and data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting two time data null and data, what is my problem? And, why should I write two time data? Is it problem with json? Can anybody help me?

[image]

Contex.js

```
class ProviderWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(URL + JSON_PATH)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return <Context.Provider value={this.state}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
  }
}
```

test.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Ctx } from "../Context/Context";

class Menu extends Component {
  static contextType = Ctx;
  render() {
    const { data } = this.context;
    console.log("data",data)
    return (
      <MenuWrapper>
        {data && data.name}
      </MenuWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking why you're getting it **twice**, right? Because the first one is obvious: your component renders before `componentDidMount` is called, and so before `data` is set to anything other than `null`.

Comment: React can render whenever it needs to. From the looks of it, it will render "null" at least once when the provider and Menu both mount the first time, and any component an ancestor (higher in the tree) of Menu can possibly trigger a render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in `ProviderWrapper` starts out `null` and you don't start the `fetch` until `componentDidMount`, so `data` will be `null` for at *least* one call to `render`. You haven't shown what `Menu` and `ProviderWrapper` are both in, but `Menu`'s `render` will be called whenever it needs to render, regardless of whether the `fetch` is done. It's not at all surprising that it does that at least once, and twice doesn't seem odd either.

`Menu` needs to be able to handle it when `data` is `null` (which it already seems to, so that's good).

---

A couple of side notes:

1. It's not the problem, but you're falling prey to a footgun in the `fetch` API: You need to check `ok` before calling `json`, details [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).
2. You're not handling errors at all. If the `fetch` fails for whatever reason, your `ProviderWrapper` is just left in the loading state forever. You need to handle errors.

Here's what that `fetch` call should look like:

```
fetch(URL + JSON_PATH)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    response.json();
  })
  .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }))
  .catch(error => {
    // ...handle/show error here and clear the loading state...
  });
```

(In my projects, I have a wrapper for `fetch` so I don't have to do that every time. Making HTTP errors fulfillments rather than rejections was a major mistake in the API.)